# NHibernate insert new record with a null many-to-one mapping

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have a Companies table mapped to a Company class and a Websites table mapped to a Website class. My Companies table is basically non-moving, however I'm trying to insert a new Website record with the following:

```
var website = new Website
{
    Active = true,
    SiteRoot = "example.com",
    CompanyId = 100     
};
var repo = new WebsiteRepository();
repo.Add(website);
```

The website class has a CompanyId property which is what maps back to the ID column in the Companies table, but because the Website class has a many-to-one mapping, it's trying to insert the `website.Company.Id` property into the table(which is null) instead of taking the `website.Id` property.

There are no foreign keys involved as the tables are in 2 separate databases.

This is the error I'm receiving:

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Models.Website][SQL: INSERT INTO Database1.dbo.Websites (CompanyID, SiteRoot, Active) VALUES (?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CompanyID', table 'Database1.dbo.Websites'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>
> NHibernate: INSERT INTO Database1.dbo.Websites (CompanyID, SiteRoot, Active) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();@p0 = NULL [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 'example.com' [Type: String (4000)], @p2 = True [Type: Boolean (0)]

Here are the mappings:

```
<hibernate-mapping assembly="Models" namespace="Models" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" schema="Database1.dbo">
  <class name="Website" table="Websites" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="ID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Company" column="CompanyID" fetch="join"/>
    <property name="SiteRoot">
      <column name="SiteRoot" sql-type="nvarchar" length="50" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Active">
      <column name="Active" sql-type="bit" not-null="true" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping assembly="Models" namespace="Models" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" schema="Database2.dbo">
  <class name="Company" table="Companies" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="ID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="CompanyId">
      <column name="CompanyID" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="CompanyName">
      <column name="CompanyName" sql-type="nchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <set name="Websites" table="Websites" schema="Database1.dbo" lazy="false">
      <key column="CID"/>
      <one-to-many class="Models.Website, Models" />
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Website class has CompanyId property with  int type i guess, so in your mapping you have CompanyID with type Company, CompanyId property must be Company type instead of int type

Comment: If I did that I wouldn't be able to map the company to the website because the website would have no CompanyId field from the DB? There must be a flag or something when saving to say "Take X from property why instead of class Z"  ?

Comment: Is there any code in the Website class? What is behind this dubious `CompanyId` property? It is not mapped to the database. There is most probably something wrong in the way you handle references.

Comment: It's also strange that your Company has two IDs. What do they mean? What should happen when you write to the CompanyId of a newly created Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a company to the Company property to implement the many-to-one relation. Something like this:

```
var website = new Website
{
    Active = true,
    SiteRoot = "example.com",
    Company = session.Load(100);
};
```

Or, if you like, use a repository:

```
var website = new Website
{
    Active = true,
    SiteRoot = "example.com",
    Company = CompanyRepository.Get(100);
};
```

**Note:**

- `session.Load` doesn't load anything from the database if lazy loading is enabled. It only creates a proxy. This is very efficient. At the end it only creates an INSERT statement for the Website with a foreign key of 100, without loosing the object oriented programming style in your code.
- Never access foreign keys in the class model. Foreign keys are managed by NHibernate and do not exist in an object oriented model.

Comment: I undid the work I put in my answer as this makes more sense, I added to my WesiteRepository: website.Company = session.Load<Company>(website.CompanyId) which is lazily loaded so doesn't actually query for the company and then the correctly inserts the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting the many-to-one mapping to insert="false" and update="false" and then added the CompanyId property to the website mapping.